# The type or namespace name 'DefaultTemplateLexer' could not be found

Tags: c#

The official tutorial from http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ST/Five+minute+Introduction doesn't work because of DefaultTemplateLexer, how to fix ?

```
using System;
using Antlr.StringTemplate;

class Script
{
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {


StringTemplateGroup group =  new StringTemplateGroup("myGroup", @"C:\Tutorials\stringtemplate", typeof(DefaultTemplateLexer));
StringTemplate helloAgain = group.GetInstanceOf("homepage");

helloAgain.SetAttribute("title", "Welcome To StringTemplate");
helloAgain.SetAttribute("name", "World");
helloAgain.SetAttribute("friends", "Terence");
helloAgain.SetAttribute("friends", "Kunle");
helloAgain.SetAttribute("friends", "Micheal");
helloAgain.SetAttribute("friends", "Marq");

Console.Out.WriteLine(helloAgain.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the tutorial, you didn't include the `using` line:

```
using Antlr.StringTemplate.Language;
```

Which imports the namespace that `DefaultTemplateLexer` resides in.  So either include that line or fully qualify the type.